# How to select the third top record in LINQ

Tags: linq

Instead of select the top 3 records, I hope to select the top 3rd record in a single query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your query already defines the right order in your result set, you can just skip the first two using `Skip()` then finally take the third result, or null if it doesn't exist (less than 3 results):

```
var result = query.Skip(2).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

**Edit:**
Actually this can be done shorter, since the `Take(1)` and `SingleOrDefault()` can be expressed with `FirstOrDefault()` instead:

```
var result = query.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: .Take(1).SingleOrDefault() == .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @hightech: hah was just typing that up